# Sencha / Extjs 4 with GeoExt 2 - How to use

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I'm working on Sencha Architect 2 - extjs 4
i found out that GeoExt doesn't work with extjs 4. but i really need to use it so i searched and end up here https://github.com/geoext/geoext2

I'm trying to something like examples so i just add :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        GeoExt: "../geoext-2/src/GeoExt",
        // for dev use
        Ext: "http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/src"
        // for build purpose
        //Ext: "extjs-4.1.0/src"
    }
});
```

to my app.js file. but i keep getting "GeoExt is not defined" error message.

anyone could help me with that ?

**EDIT**

I couldn't find a way to insert a map in my panel using GeoExt-2 , my files :

app.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.0.7-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.0.7-commercial/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: [
        'MyController'
    ]
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your GeoExt directory is getting mapped correctly? I would check your chrome/firebug inspector to verify. I created a quick jsfiddle that shows one of those github geoext2 examples with a correct GeoExt path set - http://jsfiddle.net/leewhitbeck/rgEyV/

Comment: Thank you Lee ! now I am wondering how to do that - i mean insert a map in a panel - while I have these files (i updated my post)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of different approaches coming mostly from the [github](https://github.com/geoext/geoext2) examples

1) You can simply add the map in your application launch - 
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/leewhitbeck/rgEyV/1/)

2) You can create a map view and add it to the panel in the viewport - [js fiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/leewhitbeck/rgEyV/3/)